# Registering class by multiple abstractions while creating the type by hand

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I want to register class `Foo` and its interface `IBar`.

```
var b = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
b.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Connect.Device;Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true;");
_container.Register(() => new DeviceContext(b.Options), Lifestyle.Scoped);
_container.Register<IFoo, DeviceContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
_container.Register<IDeviceTypeService, DeviceTypeService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

This does not work. This is the exception which is thrown on call to `Verify`:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The
>   configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IFoo failed.
>   The constructor of type DeviceContext contains the parameter with name
>   'options' and type DbContextOptions that is not registered. Please
>   ensure DbContextOptions is registered, or change the constructor of
>   DeviceContext.   Source=SimpleInjector   StackTrace:    at
>   SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding()    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt(InstanceProducer[]
>   producersToVerify)    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt()    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean
>   suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.Verify(VerificationOption option)    at
>   Connect.Device.Service.Startup.InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder
>   app) in Startup.cs:line 85    at
>   Connect.Device.Service.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env) in Startup.cs:line 50
>
> Inner Exception 1: ActivationException: The constructor of type
>   DeviceContext contains the parameter with name 'options' and type
>   DbContextOptions that is not registered. Please ensure
>   DbContextOptions is registered, or change the constructor of
>   DeviceContext.

Comment: Please post the exact exception message. And please make sure your code is a MCVE (i.e. make sure it compiles).

Comment: @Steven updated the question.

Comment: I don't see any information about the class having a default constructor.

Comment: @Steven Ok, it complains that `DeviceContext` does not have parameterless constructor, but the constructor which requires parameter which is not registered. The question is why does container ignores the fact, that `DeviceContext` is alredy registered.

Comment: @Steven This is a followup question to this [one](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/622). I just tried to move `DeviceContext` registration from `ConfigureServices` to `InitializeContainer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A registration using `Register<TService, TImplementation>` (such as your `Register<IFoo, DeviceContext>`) always uses auto-wiring by analyzing the type's constructor. It will not reuse a previous registration that uses a delegate.

You wish to overwrite auto-wiring and hand-wire `DeviceContext`, while being able to resolve it by multiple of its types. The way to achieve this is as follows:

```
var reg = Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(
    () => new DeviceContext(b.Options), container);
container.AddRegistration<DeviceContext>(reg);
container.AddRegistration<IFoo>(reg);
```

Here you create a `Registration` instance for `DeviceContext`, which allows you to hand-wire the type, while specifying its lifestyle. This, however, does not register it, which can be done by calling `AddRegistration` while specifying the type for which it can be resolved.